# Simple download link for an ios app without itunes

Tags: ios

I want to supply a simple link for testing purpose to download an ios app? To which file has the link to point to.

I tried that one without success:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=/static/app.plist">
click this link to install</a>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to provide full plist url.
Example :

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19281289/test/manifest.plist">Install</a>
```

For iOS 8, after you click the hyperlink, you must press the "Home" button manually to see your app installing.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7.1 Apple forces you to use HTTPS, not HTTP. That means if you are going to use a host you have, or localhost, you must have an SSL Certificate. Or else, the download will not work.